# Javascript Arrays

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

```js
function crearClasePersona() {
  class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
    // El constructor de la clase Persona recibe nombre (string), edad (integer), 
    // hobbies (array de strings), amigos (array de objetos)
    // Inicializar las propiedades de la persona con los valores recibidos como argumento

    // Tu código aca:

      this.nombre= nombre;
      this.edad= edad;
      this.hobbies= hobbies;
      this.amigos= amigos;
    }

    addFriend(nombre, edad) {
    // El método 'addFriend' recibe un string 'nombre' y un entero 'edad' y debe 
    // agregar un objeto:
    // { nombre: nombre, edad: edad} al arreglo de amigos de la persona.
    // No debe retornar nada.

    // Tu código aca:

      var amigo = {nombre, edad}
      this.amigos.push({amigo});
    }

    addHobby(hobby) {
    // El método 'addHobby' recibe un string 'hobby' y debe agregarlo al arreglo 
    // de hobbies de la persona.
    // No debe retornar nada.

    // Tu código aca:

      this.hobbies.push(hobby);
    }

    getFriends() {
    // El método 'getFriends' debe retornar un arreglo con sólo los nombres del arreglo de amigos
    // de la persona.
    // Ej:
    // Suponiendo que la persona tiene estos amigos: [{nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},{nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}]
    // persona.getFriends() debería devolver ['martin', 'toni']

    // Tu código aca:
      const transformarObjetoAmigoANombre = ((amigo) => amigo.nombre);
      const indexed = amigos.map(transformarObjetoAmigoANombre);
    }

    getHobbies() {
      // El método 'getHobbies' debe retornar un arreglo con los hobbies de la persona
      // Ej:
      // persona.getHobbies() debe devolver ['correr', 'dormir', 'nadar']

      // Tu código aca:
    }

    getPromedioEdad() {
      // El método 'getPromedioEdad' debe retornar el promedio de edad de los amigos de una persona
      // Ej:
      // Si la persona tuviera estos amigos:
      // {
      //   amigos: [{
      //     nombre: 'toni',
      //     edad: 33,
      //   }, {
      //     nombre: 'Emi',
      //     edad: 25
      //   }]
      // }
      // persona.getPromedioEdad() debería devolver 29 ya que (33 + 25) / 2 = 29

      // Tu código aca:
      var sum = this.edad.reduce((previous, current) => current += previous);
      var prom = sum / this.edad.length;{
        return prom;
      }
    }
  };
  return Persona;
}
```

Para saber si esta bien tengo que correr un test por consola, y el único que me correcto es inicializar las propiedades, no se como resolverlo. Gracias de antemano

```
  Clase
  crearClasePersona
  √ should return a user constructor that correctly builds user objects (1ms)
  × should add a friend with addFriend (14ms)
  × should add a hobbie with addHobby (1ms)
  × should get all friends with getFriends (5ms)
  × should get all hobbies with getHobbies (1ms)
  × should get age average with getPromedioEdad
```

Comment: No necesitas push, ni usar reduce. Si quieres un arreglo con solo los nombres, puedes usar map. amigos.map(amigo => amigo.nombre). Aquí está la documentación para que lo revises más a profundidad: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Comment: No reutilices preguntas, crea nuevas preguntas o las respuestas dejarán de tener sentido

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo que utilices el método `Array.prototype.map()` para conseguir lo que andas buscando. Este método te permite crear un nuevo arreglo, tomando como base otro, a medida que aplicas una función a sus elementos. En esa función puedes transformar cada uno de los objetos que componen el arreglo "amigos" a uno con solo sus nombres.

Este es un ejemplo de la solución utilizando `.map()`:

```js
const amigos = [
  {nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},
  {nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}
];

// Función que recibe el objeto amigo y retorna solo su nombre
const transformarObjetoAmigoANombre = ((amigo) => amigo.nombre);

// recorro cada uno de los objetos que componen el arreglo amigo 
// y aplico la función transformarObjetoAmigoANombre
const indexed = amigos.map(transformarObjetoAmigoANombre);

console.log(indexed); // ["martin", "toni"]
```

Otra forma de escribir el mismo ejemplo utilizando una función anonima:

```js
const amigos = [
  {nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},
  {nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}
];

const indexed = amigos.map((amigo) => amigo.nombre);

console.log(indexed); // ["martin", "toni"]
```

Si te quedan dudas, aquí puedes encontrar la documentación de método `Array.prototype.map()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map

Answer (score 2):

Usa la funcion map de javascript

```js
let amigos = [{nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},{nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}];
        
let friends = getFriends(amigos);
        
console.log(friends);
        
function getFriends(amigos) {
    amigos = amigos.map(function (amigo) {
        return amigo.nombre;
    });
          
    return amigos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function crearClasePersona() {
  class Persona {
    constructor(nombre, edad, hobbies, amigos) {
      this.nombre = nombre,
      this.edad = edad,
      this.hobbies = hobbies,
      this.amigos = amigos,
      this.persona = function(){
        return{
          nombre: this.nombre,
          edad: this.edad,
          hobbies: this.hobbies,
          amigos: this.amigos,
        }
      }
    }
    addFriend(nombre, edad) {
      let amigo = {nombre, edad}
      this.amigos.push(amigo);
    }
    addHobby(hobby) {
      this.hobbies.push(hobby);
    }
    getFriends() {
      const transformarObjetoAmigoANombre = ((amigo) => amigo.nombre);
      const indexed = this.amigos.map(transformarObjetoAmigoANombre);
      return indexed
    }
    getHobbies() {
      return this.hobbies
    }
    getPromedioEdad() {
      return this.amigos.map(amigo => amigo.edad).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.amigos.length
    }
  };
  return Persona;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A continuación es cómo la haría utilizando `push`.

```js
let persona = {
  amigosArray : [
  {nombre: 'martin', edad: 31},
  {nombre: 'toni', edad: 33}
]   
}

persona.getFriends = function(){
let ry = []
for (const p of persona.amigosArray) {
     ry.push(p.nombre);
 } 
  console.log(ry);
}

persona.getFriends()
```

Si necesitas utilizar `this` esto quiere decir que tienes no un objeto sino una clase de objetos.

Comment: Clase de objetos? Podrías explicarte mejor por favor